# How would I create a border with an absolute top and bottom, and fixed sides in CSS only? Image included

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

The content in pink would be behind it. I managed to create this but needed to extend the height via javascript. Window resize, onscroll, etc was the only way I could get the sides to go all the way down to connect to the bottom. I'd like to not use JS at all. Any ideas?

Added what I have so far: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rgbjoy/cpdZn/)

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #FF3300;
}
.border-top {
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    border-top: 5px solid #d3ad42;
    background: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.border-right {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-right: 5px solid #d3ad42;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.border-bottom {
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    height: 20px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    border-top: 5px solid #d3ad42;
    background: inherit;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.border-left {
    margin: 20px 0 20px 20px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-left: 5px solid #d3ad42;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.content {
    padding: 40px;
    min-height: 1400px;
}
```

JS:

```
var WIDTH, HEIGHT, SCROLL;

document.addEventListener("scroll", resize, false);

function resize() {
    HEIGHT = $(window).height();
    WIDTH = $(window).width();
    SCROLL = $(document).scrollTop();

    // BORDER
    $('.border-left').height(HEIGHT + SCROLL - parseInt($('.border-left').css('margin-top'), 10) * 2);
    $('.border-right').height(HEIGHT + SCROLL - parseInt($('.border-right').css('margin-top'), 10) * 2);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any base markup to work with? What exactly should happen when you scroll?

Comment: calc, -webkit-calc, etc

Comment: Just to wrap my mind around this, this is a block that does scroll vertically with the page, but remains in place in the window when you scroll horizontally??

Comment: So the top and bottom borders move with the page, but the sides remain stationary?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/body-border/

Comment: This is what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/rgbjoy/cpdZn/

Comment: You could do it by using divs to create the effect. You couldn't do it with one wrapper div in CSS only as the wrapper needs to change in height with user intervention.

Comment: Did you check out the jsfiddle? It is divs. I'm just trying to figure it out with pure css.

Comment: @Tom in your fiddle the bottom border is always visible but the top is lost when you scroll, is that the desired behavior?

Comment: yeah because the border isn't an overlay but part of the page design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want is basically a whole page overlay.

Here's an example of how to make one with CSS. [A working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xpQV/).

HTML (minimal):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="overlay">Hello!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body { position: relative }

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

A bit of explanation wouldn't hurt, I guess. `#overlay` is the element you want to make cover your whole page. The style for it is pretty straight forward. You make it absolutely positioned and anchor its sides to the sides of the page.

Now, only that would not be enough. You've noticed that it won't cover whole page. Only the part before the fold. Why is that? That's because by default `#overlay` would have `html` element as a containing block. It only spans the size of viewport. There are ways to make it span all the way down to the bottom of the page it's easier just to make `body` to be a containing block for the overlay. And changing `position` to `relative` does exactly that.

*Update*: Originally there was no example. You'd need four elements to replicate it but the technique I described is still applicable. With only one element you can replicate it visually bit it will cover content and users would be unable to select it or click links or interact in any other way.

Comment: Ok the problem with this is when body, html is 100%. I need the border to fill the window when the content isn't long enough but extend with the content if it's past window size. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/rgbjoy/7xpQV/1/